# Can I omit the noun and verb in the following sentence?

Tags: conjunction-reduction

> That the left brain is analytical and the right creative is false.

In order to avoid repetition, I omitted "brain is" after "right." Is it incorrect to do so?

Comment: It might be grammatical but it doesn't read smoothly.  This is a  time that I would use commas to slow the reader down. *That the left brain is analytical and the right, creative, is false.* This breaks up  *right creative*, which can sound like an (attempted) phrase. Still I'd prefer to rewrite it to something like *It is false that the left brain is analytical and the right creative.*

Comment: @Clare - I like your commas, I’m not so crazy about your rewrite.

Comment: Yes, it's okay. Syntactically, it exhibits both "gapped coordination" and 'fusion'. _That the left brain is analytical and the right __ creative is false_. Gap has the predicator (verb) of the first clause as antecedent, and hence can be filled with "is". Second, the adjective "right" is a fused modifier-head meaning "right brain".

Answer (score 2):

You've written three garden paths that together lead your hapless reader toward a syntactic dead end. The first arises from the dual use of *right* as a noun and an adjective, the former taking the definite article: People can be *in **the right*** or *on **the right***. But you mean this as modifier of the brain, to talk about the righthand side of that organ.

Secondly, that omission of *brain*, the noun that *right* is intended to modify even in its absence, will suggest a pattern like

> The left brain will make *the right decision*.

Even when your readers find an adjective (*creative*), they may be misled:

> That's **the right ethical decision**
>   May I present **the right honorable** Mr. Jones?

Lastly, your subject, the singular *that* (meaning *the fact that*) is a long way from its verb (*is*), with a compound complement intervening. You're one word from the nonsensical, but parallel parse:

> [T]he left brain is analytical, and the right creative is false.

Have mercy on your readers and rephrase:

> It is false to conclude that the left brain is analytical and the right, creative.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, BillJ answered:

> Yes, it's okay. Syntactically, it exhibits both "gapped coordination" and 'fusion'. *That the left brain is analytical and the right __ creative is false*. Gap has the predicator (verb) of the first clause as antecedent, and hence can be filled with "is". Second, the adjective "right" is a fused modifier-head meaning "right brain".